# Is there a way to chemically detect the presence of Fungus in a sample?

Tags: mycology

I would like to know if there is a way to chemically or somehow detect the presence of Fungus in a sample?

Comment: What kind of sample?

Comment: What kind of fungus?

Comment: Relevant literature: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3968782/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could test for the presence of chitin, which is a fundamental component of fungal cell walls.  There is precedent for this: https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a036986.pdf

Chitin is not only present in fungi though, it is also fundamental to insect and crustacean exoskeletons, and the occasional plant species (e.g. Aegagropila).

Comment: Don't insects have chitin as well, and aren't insect parts generally found at some level in many foodstuffs?